# Do I need to install a different parser library for Beauitfulsoup4? LXML is not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have downloaded lxml and beautifulsoup4 using pip3 install and both were successful. I have tried uninstalling and installing multiple times, but nothing is working. My beautifulsoup4 works fine, but lxml has not worked once since I downloaded it.

My script starts off with the following import statements which all work fine:

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
```

Then begins the code:

```
base_url = 'http://www.nytimes.com'
r = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
```

My error message is as follows:

```
Mathews-MacBook-Pro:desktop MatLefkofsky$ python3 Homework2_Final_Turnin.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Homework2_Final_Turnin.py", line 16, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml") 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

How can I fix this issue? I have been on the all the other stack pages that relate and nothing works. I am running OS X 10.11.5 on my Mac.

Comment: if you want to use lxml parser, there is no need to use bs4 , well for lxml you can do pip install lxml

Comment: what does it do when you don't pass "lxml" as parameter?

Comment: @ShekharSamanta, he says he has done it

Comment: @YannisP. I am sure there is a problem with lxml installation , See the traceback last line , **: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?**

Comment: @ShekharSamanta could be but he says he did that :)

Comment: pip install lxml